# Incompatible types for property setData [JSON+Struts2 plugin]

Tags: java, json, maven, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I need to configure JSON Plugin (https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html) with my current JAVA web application. What I've done:

1) Added to `pom.xml` file all dependencies for the plugin.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Extended the package in struts.xml with `json-default`

```
<package name="my-test-package" extends="xxx, json-default"
    namespace="/my-test-package">
```

3) Added to my action the interceptor and result type of json

```
<action name="myMainAction"
    class="org.com.action.myMainAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
           <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json">                    
        </result>           
    <param name="requiredAuthorities">F_ADD</param>
</action>
```

4) Created a Model class `Marriage` with only setters/getters in it.

5) Created the Action class, named as `myMainAction` with following code

```
private List <Marriage> data;

public List<Marriage> getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(List<Marriage> data) {
     System.out.println("Inside the setter ");
    this.data = data;
}


@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(data.get(0).getLastNameHe());

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

6) Created a `JSON` object and passed it via `ajax` to the server. I can see through Google Chrome Console, that it sends the data and it does parse the JSON object and all data is in there. However, it does throw an exception in my Eclipse and also in Chrome Console:

> Exception occurred during processing request: Incompatible types for property setData (CommonsLogger.java [qtp1144623021-22])
>   org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Incompatible types for property setData

Could you please point me to some right direction, it's almost the second day which i'm working on it but it doesn't seem to start working.

EDIT1:
The data which is being sent to java side and I can see it via Chrome console.

```
{"data":{"recordId":"123","registrationDate":"20-07-2016","hisId":"","herId":"","lastNameHe":"Asd","firstNameHe":"Asd","middleNameHe":"Asd","workPlaceHe":"","educationHe"}}
```

This is the object after it has been `JSON.stringify`-ed. 
As you can see it has the root `data` variable and then all the rest of the data goes under it. According to my logic ti has to find the `setter` of the data in my java class and then call the setters/getters of that class.
P.S I renamed the name of the classes and etc so no worries about naming conventions) I do have the right things on my production code.

EDIT2:

Thanks for pointing out to my mistake @AleksandrM. Now It throws a very strange error:

> Unparseable date: "20-07-2016" (CommonsLogger.java [qtp212900572-17])
>   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20-07-2016"

The `json` variable for this part is `registrationDate` and its implementation in JAVA:

```
 private Date registrationDate;
    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
    return registrationDate;
}

public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
    this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
```

As I understand it tries to set a `string` to `date` and it can't do it. Why the json-plugin can't convert it? Should I write something in the options/settings?

Comment: Does it work if you use defaultStack plus json interceptor instead of json interceptor only ? Does Marriage have a default no-args constructor (or no constructors) ? P.S: A Java class starting with alowercase letter is NOT good

Comment: You need to use `defaultStack` + `json` interceptor. Show the data that you're submitting.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, I dont think it's the issue of the defaultStack or the position of interceptors in struts. And no my Marraige class doesn't have any constructors. That Marraige class is connected with hibernate, to create db tables and etc, and the purpose of that class is just to be a pure model that describes it.

Comment: You have list in java code, but your json doesn't have it.

Comment: @AleksandrM, ok. Let me update the code and see what I'll get

Comment: @AleksandrM, u were right, that fixed the issue but now it raised another one. Much appreciated for your help. I've updated my question.

Comment: Write a custom converter for dates or use default format.

Comment: @AleksandrM, I'm using the default format just changed the type to be dd-MM-yyyy.. Is it possible to somehow configure it so it will understand this pattern? P.S. You may want to answer to this question, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are expecting `List<Marriage> data` in the Java code but your JSON object doesn't hold any array. Either change Java code to `Marriage data` or post array of objects in JSON.

You may also want to define other interceptors, besides `json`, for the action.
Create custom interceptor stack and reference it in your action configuration.

```
<interceptor-stack name="json-stack">
    <interceptor-ref name="json" />
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
</interceptor-stack>
```

For the date string to `Date` object conversion use default format (which is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`) <s>or create a custom [Struts type converter](https://struts.apache.org/docs/type-conversion.html)</s>.
or use `@JSON(format = "dd.MM.yyyy")` on the setter.

See [this follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38494627/1700321).

Comment: For completeness, the default format (date only RFC3339) [is available from 2.3.28](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4551), while he's using 2.3.24.1 and hence is forced to go for a converter

Comment: @AndreaLigios  
It seems like the part about json and type conversion is incorrect. Going to change it.

Comment: @AndreaLigios, I read about default format date, and I'm aware of the patch but I can't upgrade, because I use a big framework and I'm developing a separate module for it.. I don't want to deal with another framework issue, so