# Custom Struts type converter is not working

Tags: java, maven, struts2, converters, struts2-json-plugin

I do have a getter/setter for the `Date` variable, like so:

```
private Date registrationDate;

@TypeConversion(converter = "org.com.helper.DataHelper")
public Date getRegistrationDate() {
    return registrationDate;
}

@TypeConversion(converter = "org.com.helper.DataHelper")
public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
    this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
}
```

As you can see I've created a custom `struts` converter to convert the incoming string to the `Date` format and then assign it. But it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code for DateHelper:

```
public class DateHelper extends StrutsTypeConverter {

    private static final DateFormat FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    @Override
    public Object convertFromString(Map arg0, String[] values, Class arg2) {
           try {
               System.out.println(values[0]+"called from datahelper");

                return FORMAT.parse(values[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new TypeConversionException(e.getMessage());
            }
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToString(Map arg0, Object value) {
        try {
            return FORMAT.format(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TypeConversionException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

I use `struts2-json` plugin to get and parse the form data. This plugin does assign automatically all string values but I do have an issue with the `Date`.

This is how I get the data passed to Java from the form.

```
{"data":{"recordId":"123","registrationDate":"20-07-2016","hisId":"","herId":"","lastNameHe":"Asd","firstNameHe":"Asd","middleNameHe":"Asd","workPlaceHe":"","educationHe"}}
```

So, according to my understanding the code before starting to set the `registrationDate` should call the helper class and convert the string to `date` and then call the `registrationDate` setter.. but it doesn't seem to work.. I've even put a `log` call in the helper code but it doesn't show up in the eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like struts2-json-plugin doesn't use default type conversions. :(

For setting date format you can use `@JSON` annotation which has `format` property.

```
@JSON(format = "dd.MM.yyyy")
public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
    this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
}
```

JSON plugin documentation - [Customizing Serialization and Deserialization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON+Plugin#JSONPlugin-CustomizingSerializationandDeserialization).

Comment: Ooh, I see... it's strange that the OP is the first one noticing it, then :) Good Q&A

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yeah, json plugin should be really refactored.

Comment: it says "JSON cannot be resolved to a type" and there are no available libraries for me to import. It does suggests to use jacksonview..

Comment: @Daler `org.apache.struts2.json.annotations.JSON`

Comment: it's not available.. it throws an error at this import... should I add some libraries to the project? strange.. seems like I'm missing stuts2-convention-plugin... damn

Comment: @Daler Should come with `struts2-json-plugin` - https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/STRUTS_2_3_24_1/plugins/json/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/json/annotations/JSON.java.

Comment: strange... `struts2-plugin` is working fine as we all know... but i can't import that library...

Comment: @Daler Eclipse? Alt + F5, refresh.

Comment: it took me 2 days to configure the whole json-plugin.. it's working as expected now, thanks